# how i can save value from input field in radio button value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.6

```js
var $radios = $('.form-group input[name=answer]').change(function () {
  var value = $radios.filter(':checked').val();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="option">Add Options</label>
    <input type="text" name="option_text[]" class="form-control"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_button" title="Addfield">
      <img style="width: 20px;height: 20px" src="{{asset('app-assets/img/add_icon.png')}}"/>
    </a>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="clicked_radio" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I enter something in the text field it should show in the alert box. How do I make it happen? 
[image: check image]

In this image it's not showing anything in alert box. It should show `1` because I entered `1` in the input field.

Comment: can you provide your jquery code?

Comment: you can see in code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `var value = $radios.filter(':checked').val();` you get the Value of the ckecked radio button, not the value of the input.

This is a working example.

```js
$('.form-group input[name=answer]').change(function () {
  var value = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.form-control').val();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="option">Add Options</label>
    <input type="text" name="option_text[]" class="form-control"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_button" title="Addfield">
      <img style="width: 20px;height: 20px" src="{{asset('app-assets/img/add_icon.png')}}"/>
    </a>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="clicked_radio" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you!

Answer (score -1):

you can do it something like this if you just give ids to your textbox and radio button:

```
$('#textboxId').on('keydown',function(){
  $('#radiobuttonId').val($(this).value);
  alert($(this).value);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't remcommend this because it isn't object orientated.

Comment: it is object oriented

Comment: What If you have multiple radios with input? Since Ids should only identify **one** element, this isn't working.

Comment: And also, the OP wanted the value of the input if the radio button is checked, not if `keydown` triggers in the input...

Comment: actually i posted it according to the question. btw your question is valid.

Comment: No, it's not. If there are multiple radios and pultiple text inputs, your code wouldn't work!

Comment: this answer is specifically for this question, it's not a generic question though.